# Reinicializar ventana Python tkinter actualizando configuración

Tags: python, funciones, tkinter, ventana

Para hacer visibles los cambios de configuración de una ventana puedo cerrar y abrir el programa, o, abrir una nueva ventana principal con la nueva configuración, una solución más elegante. Pero cuando ejecuto la función de duplicación desaparece la ventana, y la nueva queda minimizada. No he encontrado el modo de maximizarla con código, y solo puedo hacerlo manualmente. Una vez maximizada, los duplicados que se hagan ya no se minimizan, pero creo que esto es secundario.
Adjunto un programita adaptado en el que utilizo la sentencia problemática. He probado con soluciones similares, siempre con el mismo resultado.
Desde ya, gracias anticipadas

```
import tkinter as tk
import os
import sys
# adapted from http://www.python-course.eu/python_tkinter.php

counter = 0 
def counter_label(label):
  def count():
    global counter
    counter += 1
    label.config(text=str(counter))
    label.after(1000, count)
  count()

def restart():   # ESTA ES LA SENTENCIA QUE DA ORIGEN A LA CONSULTA
  os.execl(sys.executable, sys.executable, * sys.argv) 

print("Hello from tkinter counter example!")
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Counting Seconds")
label = tk.Label(root, fg="green")
label.pack()
counter_label(label)
button = tk.Button(root, text='Stop', width=25, command=root.destroy)
button.pack()
button = tk.Button(root, text='Restart Program', width=25, command=restart)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Por lo que entiendo, usted lo que está intentando es guardar la configuración y reiniciar la ventana o solo guardar el la configuración, según su código solo está ejecutando las funciones de reiniciar el programa y cerrar y un contador, no está actualizando ninguna configuración. Le recomiendo que especifique el problema detalladamente para poder entender.